# Mod-Rewrite Rules Failing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

we have a  WP blog installed on Ubuntu  here

```
/home/himalayan/public_html/blog/index.php
```

The blog has a "brand name"  aka TAKA

```
https://www.himalayanacademy.com/blog/taka  # this URL works
```

But this fails:

```
https://www.himalayanacademy.com/taka
```

even though we have these rules

```
RewriteRule ^taka/?$ /blog/taka [R]
RewriteRule ^taka?$ /blog/taka [R]
RewriteRule taka /blog/taka
```

We are using Cloud Flare, but the blog is not cached... but as a test i use fully qualified URL's

```
RewriteRule ^taka/?$ https://www.himalayanacademy.com/blog/taka [R]
RewriteRule ^taka?$ https://www.himalayanacademy.com/blog/taka [R]
RewriteRule taka https://www.himalayanacademy.com/blog/taka [R]
```

But none works...

```
https://www.himalayanacademy.com/taka
```

always just hangs? Any clues

Answer (score 1):

You may try a Directory redirection instead. For example, through the `RedirectMatch` directive:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/taka/(.*) /blog/taka/$1
```

Your matching regex is also starting with `t` instead of `/`, perhaps it will work if you change it to `^/t` and add the "anything" `(.*)` pattern at the end. Example:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule   "^/taka/(.*)"  "/blog/taka/$1" [L,R=301]
```

Also you can try with a simple `Redirect` directive (no need for regex):

```
Redirect "/taka/" "/blog/taka/"
```

More explanations and examples in the [Apache httpd website](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html).

Comment: @user2081323 does any other redirect rule work for you? Have you confirmed a simple file redirection? (check the link from Apache's httpd website to try a few examples)